# typoscript append keywords from tt_products

Tags: typoscript

in typo3 4.4.2 I´m adding meta keywords from tt_products like this:

```
page.meta.keywords >
page.meta.keywords.cObject = RECORDS
page.meta.keywords.cObject { 
  tables = tt_products 
  source.data = Gpvar:tt_products|product 
  conf.tt_products = TEXT 
  conf.tt_products.field = subtitle 
  conf.tt_products.required = 1 
  conf.tt_products.crop = 200 | ... | 1
  conf.tt_products.stripHtml = 1
}
```

After that I also want to append also the title of the product as meta keywords. I´ve tried the := operator with no luck:

```
page.meta.keywords :=
page.meta.keywords.cObject = RECORDS
page.meta.keywords.cObject { 
  tables = tt_products 
  source.data = Gpvar:tt_products|product 
  conf.tt_products = TEXT 
  conf.tt_products.field = subtitle 
  conf.tt_products.required = 1 
  conf.tt_products.crop = 200 | ... | 1
  conf.tt_products.stripHtml = 1
}
```

How can I add more keywords from a different database field?

thanks,

t book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a COA instead of RECORDS inside `page.meta.keywords.stdWrap.append`. Thus you can add easliy whatever you want.

If `page.meta.keywords` was defined previously you need to use `stdWrap.append` or `stdWrap.prepend` to append or prepend anything.

```
page.meta.keywords.stdWrap.append = COA
page.meta.keywords.stdWrap.append {
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
    value = My page is awesome
    stdWrap {
      required = 1
      noTrimWrap = | ||
    }
  }

  20 = RECORDS
  20 {
    tables = tt_products 
    source.data = Gpvar:tt_products|product 
    conf.tt_products = TEXT 
    conf.tt_products.field = subtitle 
    conf.tt_products.required = 1 
    conf.tt_products.crop = 200 | ... | 1
    conf.tt_products.stripHtml = 1
    stdWrap {
      required = 1
      noTrimWrap = | ||
    }
  }

  30 = TEXT
  30 {
    value = whatever
    stdWrap {
      required = 1
      noTrimWrap = | ||
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure to use the following on each item you created inside the COA:

```
stdWrap {
  required = 1
  noTrimWrap = | ||
}
```

Each item will get a leading space if the content is present. Otherwise you will end up with: `keywordsdefinedprevousilyMy page is awesomeYOURRECORDSDATAwhatver`